# API Call getting error on home page slick product slider

Tags: api, magento2.4.1

I am using api for free delivery available or not for the products, producty listing page my api helper class working, path-> my app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\list.phtml if i try that helper class into my slisk slider app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_PageBuilder\templates\catalog\product\widget\content\carousel.phtml   i am getting error,

Error: Error: Call to a member function getData() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\code\Zero\my_module\Helper\ProductLabelHelper.php:156 Stack trace: #0

any help thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code of ProductLabelHelper class ?

Comment: helper: https://codeshare.io/5eOO7J

Comment: ProductLabelHelper.php:156 it’s not that code

Comment: Helper code: https://codeshare.io/5RjjgW

Comment: list.phtml please as well?

Comment: i am using the above code inside the app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_PageBuilder\templates\catalog\product\widget\content\carousel.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120313/discussion-between-zus-and-yasir-latif).